# Remove keys from object that are not in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for an elegant way to do the following:

I have a JS object:

```
     var sObject = {};
     sObject[Col1] = "Value1";
     sObject[Col2] = "Value2";
     sObject[Col2] = "Value3";
```

I also have an array

```
     var arrayCols=[];
     arrayCols.push("Col2");
```

What I am trying to do is remove all the key/values from `sObject` where Key != arrayCols `key`

Once the needful is done, my sObject should only contain  **Col2:Value2** as `Col2` is the only key in the `arrayCols`

I'm trying something along the lines of:

```js
var sObject = {};
sObject['Col1'] = "Value1";
sObject['Col2'] = "Value2";
sObject['Col2'] = "Value3";

var arrayCols = [];
arrayCols.push("Col2");

let newObject = {};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(sObject)) {
  if (key in arrayCols) {
    newObject[key] = value;
  }
}

console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: Note that I added quotes to your object key names in lines 2-4.

Comment: You can try to use filter - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @isherwood doesn't that change the issue?

Comment: Not really. There's no indication that those are variable values, and the array value implies that they were supposed to be strings. At any rate, I made it known so the question author could make corrections but the demo works without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.fromEntries` and `map`:

```js
var obj = { Col1: "Value1",  Col2: "Value2",  Col3: "Value3" };
var cols = ["Col2"];

var result = Object.fromEntries(cols.map(col => [col, obj[col]]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please add your answer to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

E. g. using `reduce`:

```js
var sObject = {};
sObject.Col1 = "Value1";
sObject.Col2 = "Value2";
sObject.Col2 = "Value3";

var arrayCols = [];
arrayCols.push("Col2");

sObject = arrayCols.reduce((a, k) => (a[k] = sObject[k], a), {})


console.log(sObject)
```

Comment: @trincot, you're right again =))